# Building a Wordpress site on Openshift to scale

Tags: wordpress, openshift, scale, openshift-gears

Openshift's default app generator sets Wordpress creation of sites to be a non-scalable version of their gears. I'd like to know if there is a way to set a scalable instance and install wordpress on it.

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am working on this today actually and got a scalable wordpress site up and running on OpenShift.  (www.runcloudrun.com)

I disabled the symlinks in the action_hooks and manually added my theme and plugins to the php/wp-content/themes and plugins directory.  I also used a S3 plugin to store all of my media files on amazon s3 so my images and media would scale once OpenShift adds addiontal gears.

I am writing a blog post on how to do all of this and it should be posted later this week.

Edit to add the blog post:   http://www.runcloudrun.com/?p=22

--
gs

Comment: Hi @gshipley , that looks promissing! Keep me posted on that blog post! Cheers

Comment: o/ ! that was great @gshipley

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout this [AppFog solution](http://hasin.me/2013/02/02/how-to-jailbreak-your-wordpress-com-blog/). And if you visit his Github you'd find an OpenShift wrapper as well. These two might give you all the sparks it needs to think out a scalable solution on Openshift.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the git source URL and create a new app with PHP.  Once the app is created, add MySQL to it.

Once you've created the app, the important next step is to check in your modules directly to the Git repo.

By default, we wanted folks to be able to download plugins directly from Wordpress, but when you scale, those files aren't copied over.  Also, the filesystem for each gear in a scaled app isn't shared, so modules uploaded after you scale aren't magically copied to all gears.  Given that limitation, we decided to mark the QuickStart not scalable, so as to prevent unfamiliar users from getting into trouble.

If you're familiar with Wordpress just check those modules in directly to your source, and everything will scale.

Comment: Thanks @Clayton , you mean the wordpress openshift default wordpress git repository? If yes, I tried that and I couldn't build the instance. I also tried making a simple Php gear and add a new wordpress isntalation with the db configured with the mySQL cartridge credentials. Ten I couldn't even load the files as I was stoped by the haproxy. I don't know much about it nor could find an easy explanation about it! thanks!